# ¿se puede cambiar entre GPS_PROVIDER y NETWORK_PROVIDER en tiempo de ejecucion?

Tags: android, geolocalización, gps

La situación es esta, cada cierto  tiempo mando la ubicación del usuario a una pequeña tabla de pruebas, la ubicación la obtengo por medio del gps , si este no estuviera activado al iniciar el servicio  obtendría la ubicación por medio de NETWORK_PROVIDER, todo funciona perfecto el detalle aquí es que si estoy usando el gps y lo desactivo  ya no manda  la ubicación del NETWORK_PROVIDER , creo que es por que el onCreate del servicio se crea así, pero ya en tiempo de ejecucion  no  puedo cambiar eso que cambie entre un provider u otro

servicioUbicacion.java

```
public class servicioUbicacion extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "ProyectoFinal";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
        Location mLastLocation;
        String ubicacion="";
        private Context mContext;
        Preferencias preff;
        int id_usuario;

        public LocationListener (String provider){
             Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
             mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //aqui se registra
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onProviderChanged"+ provider);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onProviderEnabled"+ provider);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            if(provider.equals("gps")){
                Log.e(TAG,"onProviderDisabled"+ provider);
            }
        }
}
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,this),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,this)
};
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG,"onStartComand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");    
    preff = new Preferencias(getApplicationContext());
    id_usuario; = preff.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);
   initializeLocationManager();
    try{
        if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[0]);
        }else{
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[1]);
        }        
    }catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex){
        Log.i(TAG,"Fallo la obtencion de la ubicacion, ",ex);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
        Log.d(TAG,"Provedor de red no existe, "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fallo en remover los datos de ubicacion , ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager(){
    Log.e(TAG,"inicia la localizacion");
    if(mLocationManager==null){
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(  Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es:

> ¿se puede cambiar entre GPS_PROVIDER y NETWORK_PROVIDER en tiempo de
>   ejecucion?

La respuesta es, si, lo puedes realizar.

Pero para obtener la geolocalización regularmente se revisa si esta activo alguno de los dos proveedores, lo cual esta realizando tu código y es lo correcto:

```
if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[0]);
}else{
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[1]);
}
```

Si no obtienes la localización usando el proveedor GPS entonces trata por el de la Red, si tampoco esta activo, no hay forma de obtenerlo.

**Debes asegurar tener al menos uno de los proveedores para obtener la geolocalización.**

---

Para detectar si los proveedores estan habilitados puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

> NETWORK_PROVIDER:

```
boolean network_provider_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

> GPS_PROVIDER:

```
boolean gps_provider_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: Si funciona con los dos, pero el problema es que si desactivo el GPS , ya no manda la ubicacion obtenida por la Red, en pocas palabras si se desactiva el GPS , la aplicacion continue enviando la ubicacion, estaba  intentando hacerlo con el metodo  `onProviderDisabled` y checar cuando el gps este apagado pero no funciono

Comment: Desactiva el GPS y revisa que valor obtienes con : boolean network_provider_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);  si es falso significa que no esta activo el proveedor de red, por lo tanto sería imposible obtener la geolocalización si no tienes activo el GPS.

Comment: bueno  intentare lo que me comentas, y pero para una idea mas clara de mi problema  anexo este link  en el que se muestra un caso casi totalmente parecido al mio

https://www.androidpit.com/forum/734255/network-provider-and-gps-provider-working-together-need-to-separate-the-both-based-on-available-providers

Comment: respecto al problema, el codigo no se parece en nada